# Yeoman generator copy pic but not show

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I create a Yeoman generator app [generator-phaser-h5](https://github.com/Sanchez3/generator-phaser-h5)

I use `copyTpl` to copy src,include favicon.ico and favicon.png

but When I use `generator-phaser-h5`, the pic is broken and do not show.

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is a mistake in the question, but `mkdirp` creates new empty directory. It doesn't copy content.

Comment: Thanks  I find out the problems，`this.fs.copyTpl` cause this error. Instead I use `this.fs.copy` to copy the pic.